# How to subset duplicates on the earliest date among a group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, subset

I have a `data.frame` with multiple events by individual (`id`). `Duplicated` `rows` have been previously removed.

```
df <- data.frame(id=as.integer(c(123,123,123,124,124,124,125,125,125,126,126,126)),
                 date=as.Date(c("2014-03-12", "2014-03-12", "2015-09-16", 
                                "2015-10-24", "2016-12-11", "2016-12-11", 
                                "2017-08-06", "2017-11-26", "2018-01-29", 
                                "2015-09-16", "2015-09-16", "2015-09-16")),
                 fruit=as.character(c("Apple", "Orange", "Passion fruit", "Banana", 
                                      "Lemon", "Strawberry",  "Banana", "Apple",
                                      "Passion fruit", "Orange", "Bluberry", "Pineapple")),
                 row=rep(c(1, 2, 3)))
```

```
        id       date         fruit row
    1  123 2014-03-12         Apple   1
    2  123 2014-03-12        Orange   2
    3  123 2015-09-16 Passion fruit   3
    4  124 2015-10-24        Banana   1
    5  124 2016-12-11         Lemon   2
    6  124 2016-12-11    Strawberry   3
    7  125 2017-08-06        Banana   1
    8  125 2017-11-26         Apple   2
    9  125 2018-01-29 Passion fruit   3
    10 126 2015-09-16        Orange   1
    11 126 2015-09-16      Blueberry  2
    12 126 2015-09-16     Pineapple   3
```

I need to select only the earliest date per individual that contains a duplicate, that is, if the earliest date happens more than once, I need to keep all occurrences.

**Desired Output**:

```
df
    id       date         fruit row
1  123 2014-03-12         Apple   1
2  123 2014-03-12        Orange   2
3  126 2015-09-16        Orange   1
4  126 2015-09-16      Blueberry  2
5  126 2015-09-16     Pineapple   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could group by 'id', create a condition with `min` and use `duplicated` to check for duplicates

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(date == min(date) & (duplicated(date)|
     duplicated(date, fromLast = TRUE)), .by = id)
```

-output

```
   id       date     fruit row
1 123 2014-03-12     Apple   1
2 123 2014-03-12    Orange   2
3 126 2015-09-16    Orange   1
4 126 2015-09-16  Bluberry   2
5 126 2015-09-16 Pineapple   3
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun. It does not work using the argument '.by = id'. But if you add 'group_by(id)' before the filter argument, it will work.

Comment: You probably have to update your `dplyr` version @Naomi :) `.id` is now a shortcut that you can use instead of a `groupy_by()`.

Comment: Arun, a possible [question of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77511824/16762740).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  slice_min(date, by = id) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 2, .by = c(id, date))

#>    id       date     fruit row
#> 1 123 2014-03-12     Apple   1
#> 2 123 2014-03-12    Orange   2
#> 3 126 2015-09-16    Orange   1
#> 4 126 2015-09-16  Bluberry   2
#> 5 126 2015-09-16 Pineapple   3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>