# Add signs (- or +) back to a string vector in R

Tags: r, string, function, vector, character

I have a string `Vector` as well as a set of `index` values. The `index` values can be sometimes negative or positive.

But we can use `Vector2 <- Vector[abs(index)]` to extract our desired elements from our initial `Vector`.

**Question:** Is it possible to add back the signs (`-` or `+`) from `index` between the elements of `Vector2` to achieve the `Desired_output` below?

*(NOTE: This is a toy example. `Vector` can be of any size or contain any shape of character elements and `index` can be of any length of course smaller than `Vector`. A `function`al answer is appreciated.)*

```
Vector <- c("advanced baseline", "beginner baseline", "intermediate baseline", 
  "advanced post1", "beginner post1", "intermediate post1", "advanced post2", 
  "beginner post2", "intermediate post2")

index = c(8,-2,-7,1)

( Vector2 <- Vector[abs(index)] )

Desired_output <- "beginner post2 - beginner baseline - advanced post2 + advanced baseline"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste` to merge the signs with vector elements. I guess you want to retain a minus sign for the first element but not a plus so that is removed with `sub`.

```r
add_signs <- function(vec, ind) {
  merged <- paste(ifelse(ind < 0, '-', '+'), 
                  vec[abs(ind)], 
                  collapse=' ')
  sub('^\\+ ', '', merged)
}

add_signs(Vector, index)
# [1] "beginner post2 - beginner baseline - advanced post2 + advanced baseline"
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse-solution that does the same as the [solution by Robert Hacken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77511909/4303162) with slightly different syntax:

```
library(tidyverse)

add_signs <- function(vec, ind) {
  vec %>%
    magrittr::extract(abs(ind)) %>%
    str_c(if_else(ind > 0, "+ ", "- "), ., collapse = " ") %>%
    str_remove("^\\+ ")
}

add_signs(Vector, index)
## [1] "beginner post2 - beginner baseline - advanced post2 + advanced baseline"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the slow `ifelse`.

```
> f <- \(x, i) paste0(c('', c('- ', '+ ')[1 + (i > 0)][-1]), x[abs(i)], collapse=' ')
> f(Vector, index)
[1] "beginner post2 - beginner baseline - advanced post2 + advanced baseline"
```

*Explanation:*

The trick is, that

```
> 1 + c(FALSE, TRUE)
[1] 1 2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(Vector)
c("advanced baseline", "beginner baseline", "intermediate baseline", 
"advanced post1", "beginner post1", "intermediate post1", "advanced post2", 
"beginner post2", "intermediate post2")
> dput(index)
c(8, -2, -7, 1)
```